Verb to fit: transitivity
Which of the following is the correct expression in English?

Put in as many (boxes) as you can fit
Put in as many (boxesᵢ) as theyᵢ can fit
Put in as many (boxesᵢ) as (∅ᵢ) can fit


Where exactly are you fitting the boxes? In a van? Usually, we'd say load (in a truck or van or x)

They're all possible.

The version with they seems odd to me. I would say as many as you can fit [in] or as many as will fit [in].

You have an answer, why not respond to it?

Put in as many (boxes) as you can fit. is OK.
To fit or put boxes in a space, truck, room, etc.=transitive

You can fit many boxes in that room.=transitive

But not all action verbs require stating the object:

Play [the song] as well as you can.

Put in as many as they can fit. It only works if they refers to a place.


If they referred to rooms, that would give us: Put in as many boxes as the rooms can fit. However, that is an incorrect use of fit. Because things (rooms) don't fit things. People fit things in a place or thing.

Put in as many as (can) fit. [okay]


Please ignore the downvote.
